# jQuery onChange send value of select to JsTree using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jstree

I am trying to send the value of a select to a file called "response.php?operation=get_node&idcuatrimestre=..." (this returns JSON code of JsTree and returns different results depending on the second parameter "idcuatrimestre"). The problem is that using AJAX if you send the parameter but do not know how to refresh JsTree so that it changes the value of said

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="idcuatrimestre" onchange="fetch_select_left(this);" class="select">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="test-result">#nc</div>

<div id="tree-container"></div> <!-- Here load the JsTree menu -->

<script>    <!-- Send to response -->
    function fetch_select_left(idcuatrimestre){
        var idc = idcuatrimestre.value; //alert(idc);   //value of Select
        $.ajax({
            url: "../ajax/jstree/response.php",
            data: { operation: "get_node", idcuatrimestre: idc }, //Equals to:  "response.php?operation=get_node&idcuatrimestre=..." + idc,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(html){
                //alert(html);
                $("#test-result").html(html);   //Here it does a test, it just returns the value of the select and writes it in a div #test-result
                //This is where in theory I should refresh JTree with the new value but I do not know how
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And that's how I initialize JsTree when I enter the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        //fill data to tree  with AJAX call
        $('#tree-container').jstree({
            'core' : {
                'data' : {
                    'url' : '../ajax/jstree/response.php?operation=get_node',   //Final
                    'data' : function (node) {
                    return { 'id' : node.id, 'text' : node.text };
                },
                "dataType" : "json"
            }
            ,'check_callback' : true,
            'themes' : {
                'responsive' : false
            }
        },
        'plugins' : ['state','contextmenu','wholerow','search']
        })
        .on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            $.get('response.php?operation=create_node', { 'id' : data.node.parent, 'position' : data.position, 'text' : data.node.text })
                .done(function (d) {
                    data.instance.set_id(data.node, d.id);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    data.instance.refresh();
                });
            }).on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                $.get('response.php?operation=rename_node', { 'id' : data.node.id, 'text' : data.text })
                    .fail(function () {
                        data.instance.refresh();
                    });
                }).on('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                    $.get('../ajax/jstree/response.php?operation=delete_node', { 'id' : data.node.id })
                        .fail(function () {
                            data.instance.refresh();
                        });
                    })
                    //Solo para trabajar con un nodo a nivel "cargas": ...

                    //No todos los nodos tienen habilitado el plugin "contextmenu"
                    .on('show_contextmenu.jstree', function(e, reference, element) {
            //                  if ( reference.node.parents.length < 1 || reference.node.parents.length > 1 //Este solo deshabilita los planes
                                if (  reference.node.parents.length < 1 || reference.node.parents.length > 1 || reference.node.parents.length > 1  
                                // || reference.node.parents.length > 2 
                                ) {
                                      $('.vakata-context').remove();
                                };
                            })

                //Links
            //              .on("activate_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                            .on("activate_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                                if(data.node) {
                                    var href = data.node.a_attr.href;
                                    window.location.href = href;
                                }
                            })                

            });
</script>
```

Both parts work but I want to combine it so that jsTree returns JSON different according to the options of a Select. I hope you have explained me well and please can you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using AJAX for loading data, a refresh on the jsTree will trigger the url defined in the core.data.url of the configuration. So when the value of your select input changes you should add the 'idcuatrimestre' to the jstree ajax callback and then refresh the tree. The refresh method then refreshes the entire tree with the new callback.

```
function fetch_select_left(sel){
    var oTree = $('#tree-container').jstree(true);
    var idc = sel.value;
    oTree.settings.core.data = {
        'url' : '../ajax/jstree/response.php?operation=get_node',   //Final
        'data' : function (node) {
            return { 'id' : node.id, 'text' : node.text, idcuatrimestre: idc };
        }
    };
    oTree.refresh();            
}
```

Comment: My bad, guess the second last line had an error, should work now. I have edited the code.